# Importing class from another project doesn't work

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to use a class of another project in an app. In Eclipse I've added in the project properties under Java Build Path the other project and under Libraries the the class folder of the project. In the Package Explorer at Referenced Libraries the referencend class is visible under (default package).

While writing the code I could use the referenced class without problems and compiling the app throws no warning or errrors, but when the app starts, logcat shows the following:

```
dalvikvm(16174): Could not find class 'de.project.myproject1.myclass', referenced from method de.project.myproject2.myActivity.onCreate

AndroidRuntime(15570): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
AndroidRuntime(15570): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de.project.myproject1.myclass
AndroidRuntime(15570):  at de.project.myproject2.myActivity.onCreate(KeyGenActivity.java:45)
AndroidRuntime(15570):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
AndroidRuntime(15570):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
AndroidRuntime(15570):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
AndroidRuntime(15570):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
AndroidRuntime(15570):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
AndroidRuntime(15570):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
AndroidRuntime(15570):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
AndroidRuntime(15570):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
AndroidRuntime(15570):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
AndroidRuntime(15570):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
AndroidRuntime(15570):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
AndroidRuntime(15570):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
AndroidRuntime(15570):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
ActivityManager(  971):   Force finishing activity de.project.myproject2/.myActivity
ActivityManager(  971): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{4407ee10 de.project.myproject2/.myActivity}
```

So has someone a hint, what to do to solve the problem, I've spent the whole day without a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest trying to export the Eclipse project as a jar, and add the jar to the build path of your Android project.  Otherwise, if you have control over the other Eclipse project, then try creating an [Android Library project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject) and moving the code into that instead.

Finally, you should be able to add the source from the Eclipse project as a path in your Android project.  This way, the Android project will compile and include the sources.

Comment: I've exported the class now as jar. The only anoying thing of this way is, that I have to repeat it everytime I change the class in the main project.

Comment: The other methods I suggested would definitely overcome that problem.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to add the class folder of the other project anywhere, that sounds wrong to me. I'm guessing this is what's messing things up for you...

As far as I remember (it's a while since I had to do this) the simplest way to use the class from the other project is:
1. Add the other project to the build path (Java Build Path->Projects tab->Add...)
2. Make sure the other project is exported as part of the build process (Java Build Path->Order and Export tab->tick the other project where it appears in the list).

The other way would be to reference the other project as a library. Either as elevine suggests, or just by compiling the other project into a jar and referencing that file.

Comment: This worked for me. I also prefer this solution over making the project an Android library, since it doesn't have anything with Android.